# What is the best way for players to create their own NPCs to aid them in their adventures?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, npc

Has anyone tried allowing players to have NPCs of their own?  For example, a Wizard may want to employ a warrior style body guard.  How would a player go about creating their own NPC?  If they can create their own, how is this done?

Comment: I’ve re-held’s this as “unclear”. You seem to be asking two things, and it’s not clear which one the question is actually about. Is your question 1) how **players** can **create** NPCs of their own, or 2) how **PCs** can **hire** NPCs to work for them? Those are very different questions with different answers; which are you asking?

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more information before we can provide a decent answer to this question. Include things like why you want the players to have this, if you want them to be controlled by the player or the DM, what sort of campaign you are running and how big your party is. If you [edit] this information into the question along with clarifying what SSD said above we should be able to answer this.

Comment: Have you looked at the WoTC site on line?  [Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA_Sidekicks.pdf) has a variety of optional/playtests rules that you may wish to review before you refine your question.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I never knew that document existed not where to go to find it.  It is unfortunate that you considered my original question irrelevant.  Your response was very helpful and exactly what I needed.  I suspect others that are getting started and aren't aware of where to find this kind of info would have also found this question useful.  </my2cents>

Comment: @Yendor I don't feel that your question is irrelevant, and I am sorry that you feel that I do.  These two questions seemed to me to be the same topic.  I am glad that some good came out of this.